# Reflection not working for DevExpress.XtraGrid dll

Tags: c#, devexpress, system.reflection

I am using Reflection to get all the Types of DevExpress.XtraGrid assembly, but its throwing me the ReflectionTypeLoadException within a windows app.
My Code:

```
var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\References\DevExpress.XtraGrid.v7.3.dll");
var theType1 = DLL1.GetTypes();//exception here
```

Actually I want to get all properties of Type DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn class within the dll.just tried to get all Types as its not getting for the Type mentioned.I want this:

```
var DLL1 = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\References\DevExpress.XtraGrid.v7.3.dll");
var theType1 = DLL1.GetType("DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn");//theType1 is giving null
```

I have tested the same for System.Windows.Forms.Label Type in System.Windows.Forms dll. It worked perfectly, donno why not for DevExpress controls.

~Deepthi

Comment: I don't have devexpress so i can't test but my bet is they're using obfuscation and the information you need for reflection isn't there at runtime, in which case the answer would be "you can't do this"

Comment: in msdn: [If the GetTypes method is called on an assembly and a type in that assembly is dependent on a type in an assembly that has not been loaded (for example, if it derives from a type in the second assembly), a ReflectionTypeLoadException is thrown. It can also happen with assemblies loaded using the Load and LoadFile methods if the second assembly cannot be located when the GetTypes method is called.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes(v=vs.110).aspx) so possibly you need load some other dll also

Comment: There is no `GetTypes` which takes single parameter, post the original code.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, methinks in second case just a typo :-)

Comment: ~Grundy:Yep i have observed that it fails for a particular type within the litst.But how do i load that second assembly within the same context/instance & how would i get to know the second assembly name so as to load that too.

Comment: methinks, you can find required assemblies [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3124)

Answer (score 0):

yes you will get error because DevExpress.XtraGrid is depend on another dll.i think you have to load all dll that is required to DevExpress.XtraGrid dll

Comment: Hi pramod, how can i get to know all the dependent dlls of DevExpress.XtraGrid dll.Searching in DevExpress website, but no clue.

Comment: @Deepthi i am using higher version.

Comment: DevExpress.data  , DevExpress.printing  , DevExpress.Utils ,DevExpress.xtraeditor   ,DevExpress.xtralayout  ,DevExpress.xtraprinting       in my version these dll used

Comment: one more confusion...how do i load these dependendent dlls too while loading the DevExpress.XtraGrid dll. i mean Assembly.LoadFile/LoadFrom takes a single path, or do we have some other Assembly load methods??

Comment: why you are not adding this dll reference to your project why you are getting dynamically